# Reference file from Azure function 2.0 with .net core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions, filereference, geolite2

I am trying to create an Azure function that reads from a .mmdb file [GeoLite2 Country DB](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/)

I have added the geolite2 file next to my function. But I cannot find a way programmatically to reference the file path such that it remains the same on my local machine as well as deployed/published.

```
string GeoLocationDbPath = "D:<path_to_project>\Functions\GeoLocation-Country.mmdb"
var reader = new DatabaseReader($"{GeoLocationDbPath}");
```

I came across this article [How to add assembly references to an Azure Function App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/04/13/how-to-add-assembly-references-to-an-azure-function-app/)

I was hoping there was a better way to reference a file both locally and deployed.

Any ideas?

---

Other links I've looked at:

[How to add and reference a external file in Azure Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627742/how-to-add-and-reference-a-external-file-in-azure-function)

[How to add a reference to an Azure Function C# project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985925/how-to-add-a-reference-to-an-azure-function-c-sharp-project)

[Retrieving information about the currently running function](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Retrieving-information-about-the-currently-running-function)

[Azure functions – Read file and use SendGrid to send an email](http://taswar.zeytinsoft.com/azure-functions-read-file-use-sendgrid-send-email/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path to folder by injecting `ExecutionContext` to your function:

```cs
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ExecutionContext context)
{
    var funcPath = context.FunctionDirectory; // e.g. d:\home\site\wwwroot\HttpTrigger1
    var appPath = context.FunctionAppDirectory; // e.g. d:\home\site\wwwroot
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the .mmdb file is not present on the server. 

I believe there is an extra build step I would need to do to copy it to the right directory??

Comment: In Kudu I can look inside that directory
`D:\home\site\wwwroot\<myfunction>ls`

`function.json`

My .mmdb file is not there

Comment: @Sarah You can add your file to Visual Studio project, mark it as Content and Copy to Output

Comment: Ahh okay, I have found an internal method that is working. So I haven't checked if "Copy to Output" will work. Hopefully this will be helpful of others that stumble across this :)

Answer (score 0):

I've come to the conclusion that referencing files local to the Azure function was not a good approach. I read the [Azure functions best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices) and Azure functions are meant to be stateless. Also, folder structure changes when you deploy.

If I were to continue I would upload the .mmdb file to a Azure blob container and use the [CloudStorageAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount?view=azure-dotnet) to access the file.